# mySQL: Get data from two tables relationed by an ID

Tags: mysql

I need your help. I have two tables: products and presentations with the next structure and data:

```
products:
id | name | description | price
5  | iPad | description | 950.00   

presentations:
id_product | name  | price
5          | White | 955.00
5          | Black | 945.00
```

I need to get a product by id from the 'products' table and all records related to it from 'presentations' table. I want the next result in a html table or divs:

```
Product name: Ipad
Description: This is the description based on the text contained if the field of the table

Please, select the ipad you want:        
  (*) Normal - price:  $950.00
  ( ) White  - price:  $955.00
  ( ) Black  - price:  $945.00
```

How can I do it? Thanks to all!

Comment: `UNION` will work...  However, it's far better to just add a "Normal" presentation and remove price from the products table.  (Or perhaps have only an avg_price in products table or similar)  Of course, I've never seen the color "Normal" so I'm not sure how you could sell an iPad that is truly colorless...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Normal' AS name, price from products
  WHERE id = 5
UNION
SELECT name, price FROM presentations
  WHERE id_product = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

use the request

```
select name from products where id=5 and  id in(select id_product from presentations);
```

or

```
select name from products P, presentations Pr whre P.id=Pr.id_product and P.id=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN,

```
SELECT p.name,p.description,p.price,pr.name  AS presentationName,pr.price AS 
presentationPrice
FROM product p INNER JOIN presentations pr ON p.id=pr.id_product WHERE p.id='5'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not understanding you wrong, I think that what you need is a JOIN between the two tables. Something like

```
SELECT prod.name AS product_name, description, pres.name AS presentation_name, pres.price AS price 
FROM products AS prod INNER JOIN presentations AS pres 
ON (prod.id = pres.id_product)`
```

Will return results like:

| product_name | description | presentation_name | price  |

| iPad         | description | White             | 955.00 |

And so on. Is that what you wanted?